# Increase playback speed of flash video in Firefox

Tags: firefox, video, flash

Is it possible to increase the playback speed of a flash video in Firefox? Ideally, I'd like to adjust it, so that I can play the important sections slower.

Comment: One of the advantages of HTML5 video is that it is easier to change the playback speed. HTML5 Youtube has this option built in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to enounce.com.  they have software called MySpeed ($30).  You can speed up or slow down flash video in any browser.  i love it.  I can slow it down to take notes, or speed it up through parts that I don't need notes but still would like to hear.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt this is possible. An alternative is [to download the video](https://superuser.com/questions/6675/youtube-and-google-video-downloaders) and play the file on a media player like VLC/ Media Player Home Classic and change the playback speeds there.